# How can I get the code coverage information for a C program who trapped in infinite loop?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, code-coverage

I need to get the code coverage information for a amount of C programs. I only need to know whether or not each line is executed. However, some of them will never end for the sake of infinite loops. The most of tools, e.g. like gcov, llvm-cov, which could get the information for the program only after it ends. 
I set a time limitation for all the programs. If it dosen't end when its exection time is beyound the limitation, its process will be killed. However, when its process was killed, all the information stored in the memory is cleaned. So I can't get the code coverage information for those programs. How can I do that?

Comment: and if you interrupt with Ctrl+C what happens?

Comment: The instrumentation for dumping the info is probably implicit at end of program, isn't it? Can you do it explicitly? Then you could dump when doing the endless loop first time, at the end.

Comment: If I interrupt it with Crtl+C, all the information stored in the memory will lost. So I can get nothing.

Comment: Yeah, I use tools like llvm-cov and gcov. Both of them seem to dump the info at the end of the program. And I can not know whether or not I could do it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to add a litle timer interrupt inside your program that will raise an exception after a few seconds of "bad behaviour" and cause the program to terminate nicely.

When searching and probing in the temporary fashion you seem to be after, it is completely legit to "hack it" as long as you remove the hack immediately you found the error..